# How to find duplicates in a LINQ Group collection

Tags: c#, linq, grouping

I want to write a LINQ query that will check whether there is duplication of `User` data in my `InfoObject` objects.

In the succeeding illustration, I want to group by `Code` (i.e., `XYZ`) and check whether for that group, there is a `User` that has more than one `Type`. The User model contains the `Name` (e.g., John) and `Value` (1 means selected).

My model classes are as follows:

```
public class InfoObject
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public List<User> Users { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

**Invalid Case:** John is not allowed to have both types A and B

```
Code          Type          John          Luke          Tim
XYZ           A             1             1             -
XYZ           B             1             -             1
```

**Valid Case:** Each user can only have one type

```
Code          Type          John          Luke          Tim
XYZ           A             -             1             -
XYZ           B             1             -             1
```

What is the proper LINQ query to achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: Is it LINQ-to-objects or actual source of data is some database you are accessing via ORM?

Comment: this is purely C# objects and no database involved. I'm actually thinking of a logic that will check the sum of each User occurrence. if there sum is more than 1, then it's a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can flatten the `InfoObject` hierarchy and then group by user name and keep items having more than 1 unique code:

```
IEnumerable<InfoObject> data = ...;

var invalidUserNames = data
    // flatten with SelectMany:
    .SelectMany(o => o.Users
        .Where(user => user.Value == "1") // assuming you want to check only "selected"
        .Select(user => (user.Name, Obj: o))) 
    .GroupBy(t => t.Name) // assuming Name uniquely identifies user
    .Select(gr => (Name: gr.Key, Count: gr.Select(t => t.Obj.Code).Distinct().Count()))
    .Where(t => t.Count > 1)
    .Select(t => t.Name)
    .ToArray();
```

You can manipulate `Select` to expose only needed data for your final result.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I needed. I changed the Distinct() grouping. Instead of t.Obj.Code, I used t.Obj.Type to satisfy my condition.